# Can you mix Tailwind with vanilla CSS?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am very new to Tailwind, and want to incorporate it into an existing react project.  Can I use Tailwind along with all of my current CSS/sass files?  Or do I need to start over with styling and only use Tailwind?

Comment: Tailwind at the most basic level is just css files. You can use both yours and Tailwind. You'll find that some of your styles may change though. The idea of Tailwind is to give you a base level of styling and tools to help you build something unique. So to answer the question, no you don't need to start over.

Answer (score 11):

To ensure that your current CSS doesn't get overridden. You can add a [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration/#prefix) to the `tailwind.config.js`

**Example:** (source: tailwind.com)

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
   prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

Will generate classes with the prefix `.tw-` like `.tw-{class}`:

```css
.tw-text-left {
    text-align: left;
}
.tw-text-center {
    text-align: center;
}
.tw-text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
/* etc. */
```